# Cauchy integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Can someone please help me answer this question as I cannot seem to get to the answer.
Please note that the Cauchy integral formula must be used in order to solve it.

Many thanks in advance!
\begin{equation*}
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}=\pi i\sin(2t).
\end{equation*}

Also $|z| = 3$ is given the counterclockwise direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know that using the residue theorem would be easier, but if we are to restrict ourselves to [**Cauchy's integral formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), then here's one way of attacking it:

First, note that the integrand is a quotient of two entire functions.  As such, the integrand is analytic everywhere except the points at which the denominator is zero.  Since $z^2+4$ can be factored as $(z-2i)(z+2i)$, then the only points at which the integrand is not analytic are $\pm 2i$.  Unfortunately, both of these points are inside the circle $|z| = 3$, so in order to apply Cauchy's integral formula, we will have to be clever.

Let $C$ be the circle $|z| = 3$ oriented counterclockwise.  Let $C_1$ be the upper half of the circle $|z| = 3$ together with the line segment $[-3, 3]$ oriented counterclockwise.  Let $C_2$ be the lower half together with the line segment $[-3, 3]$ oriented counterclockwise.  Notice we have:

$$\int_C \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4} \ dz = \int_{C_1} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}  \ dz + \int_{C_2} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}  \ dz$$

Now we can attack the two integrals on the right hand side separately using Cauchy's integral formula.  For the first, e.g., you can let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{zt}}{z+2i}$, which is analytic everywhere inside $C_1$, and your integrand becomes $\displaystyle \frac{f(z)}{z-2i}$.

---

**Alternative method**:

Using partial fraction decomposition, we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^2+4} = \frac{i}{4(z+2i)} - \frac{i}{4(z-2i)}$.  Hence:

$$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2+4} \ dz = \int_C \frac{i}{4(z+2i)} \ dz - \int_C \frac{i}{4(z-2i)} \ dz$$

And then one can apply Cauchy's integral formula on the two separate pieces without having to split the contour.

Comment: Thank you! this was very well explained. I want to show you my solution but I'm not sure if you would be able to get it since I do not know how to use LaTeX.

Comment: I followed the steps that you provided and I got my integrals. Which equaled to (Pi/2 * e^(2*t*i )  - (Pi/2 * e^(-2*i*t)) which lead me to Pi*i*sin(2t). 
Does that seem correct ?

Comment: I didn't look *too* carefully, but the first part looks correct, and you're good if that does indeed simplify down to $(i\pi)  \sin(2t)$ when you apply Euler's formula.

Comment: Thank for all you help. it was very clear and understandable.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Write integral in the form the function in the form $\frac{e^{zt}}{(z-2i)(z+2i)}$. Then you should split the contour in two parts such that interior of each part contain only one point $2i$ or $-2i$.

Then apply Cauchy integral formula for each contour.

Answer (score 2):

Since all the poles of the integrand are enclosed by the contour, we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}dz=2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{e^{\frac{t}{z}}}{\frac{1}{z^2}+4}=2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{\frac{t}{z}}}{1+4z^2}
\end{eqnarray}
Note that 
$\displaystyle \frac{e^{\frac{t}{z}}}{1+4z^2}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n4^nz^{2n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n! z^n}\right)$. So $\displaystyle\text{Res}_{z=0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n4^nt^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The denominator $\displaystyle z^2+4=(z-2i)(z+2i)$ of the function
$$
z \longmapsto \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}
$$ gives two poles inside $|z|=3$ and by the Cauchy integral formula we have
$$
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}dz=2i\pi\left({\rm{Res}}_{z=-2i}f(z)+{\rm{Res}}_{z=2i}f(z)\right).
$$ You conclude using for example
$$
{\rm{Res}}_{z=-2i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to -2i}\left((z+2i)\times\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+4}\right)=\ldots
$$